# onAuthStateChanged() fires 5 times on signOut()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, quasar-framework

I'm having issues in my Quasar App where on login and signout, onAuthStateChanged() fires multiple times. On signOut, it fires multiple times from the signOut() action from the store. I would think that on signOut(), onAuthStateChanged() would fire once.

**Store signOut action from index.js**

```
async signOut() {
  await signOut(auth)
    .then((res) => {
      this.user = null;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // An error happened.
    });
```

**In the router index.js file**

```
Router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const authStore = useGenStore();
   console.log("router start");
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log("inituser"); <---RUNS 5 TIMES
    initUser(user)
      .then(() => resolve(user))
      ;
   });
 });
```